# Fragment error while implement

Tags: android, android-fragments

I an new to android and i am now learning about fragment but when i start implementing then i am facing this problem which i cant resolve.

```
        public void loadFragment2(View view) {
            fragmentOne one = new fragmentOne();
            FragmentTransaction fr = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fr.replace(R.id.frameLayout,one);
            fr.addToBackStack(null);
            fr.commit();
        }
```

[image: THe image is here]
What can i do ?

Comment: What's the error ? You should maybe post it..

Comment: Does your fragment implements `support fragment` or regular one? Try to switch.

Comment: @jobairahmed you need to implement `support.v4.Fragment`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume that this is your class.

```
import android.app.support.v4.Fragment; // Note this import

public class fragmentOne extends Fragment {

}
```

And you are using an `AppCompatActivity`, then, you need to use `getSupportFragmentManager()`

And you don't need to declare objects one line at a time - That'll likely fix the imports in the Activity class.

```
    public void loadFragment2(View view) {
        fragmentOne one = new fragmentOne();

        getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.frameLayout,one)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks  for your kind help

Answer (score 0):

Check that u import classes correctly:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

or

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
```